# Rigify Eye Bones disappearing and interacting strangely with mesh

Tags: bones, rigify

I'm working on an animated model for a Uni project, making do with a basic Rigify armature for posing and a walk cycle. Everything else in the rig is working okay, but the eyes are a problem.

The main issue was with the eyes 'popping out' of the head as soon as any other controls in the rig were moved. I tried to fix them by looking at the parenting and noticed that somehow the MCH bone for the left eye was missing and a series of dotted lines seemed to indicate that the right MCH bone and the missing left MCH were interacting very strangely with the model. I need to get this fixed to complete my project and would really appreciate some help.

EDIT: This question has been answered. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Please share your blend file. ([How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help))  It's almost impossible to solve complex rigging problems without one.

Comment: Added the Blend file, apologies.

Comment: You have parented the *left* eye to the *MCH-eye.R* bone.

Comment: It seems the left eye bone is missing, or unselectable. I mirrored the right eye bone and made a new MCH-eye.L, then parented the left eye to it - lots of weird things happened. The right eye popped out of its socket but 'fixed' itself in Pose mode despite its controller now being inverted, and the left went flying. I'd like to redo the eye bones completely but the rest of the rig is fine and I'd rather not have to redo everything. Adding the updated Blender file above.

Comment: The first version you had uploaded worked for me when I parented the left eye to the MCH-eye.L bone. If you noticed that in the rig bones are missing it might be better to recreate the rig from the meta rig.

Comment: Thank you, it turns out I was selecting 'connected' instead of 'parent to bone'. For some reason the 'connected' option was my only choice for the left eye, until I switched between edit and pose mode a couple times. All fixed now!